# Is there a standard name for the card game "Elevenses"?

Tags: identify-this-game, solitaire

My mother taught me a simple single player card game called Elevenses when I was young. I'm wondering: **does my card game have a standard name?** I have not met many who have known of the game.

You start with a suit 3x3 grid of playing cards from the top of a shuffled deck. The aim is to get rid of the cards in the deck by placing them over 2 cards on the grid that equal eleven when added together. The player can also place cards over three face cards on the grid. This must be done at least once and an odd number of times, otherwise you will be left with one card in the deck at the end.

Ace has the value of 1, and face cards have the value of 10.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The name is **Elevens** from wiki:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elevens